# C pipes inter process communication

Tags: multithreading, process, pipe, ipc, child-process

I try to understand inter process communication in C with pipes.
In the following code snippet I fork my program.
Thats why I think both processes should work without waiting for the other. But when I run, I can type sth. in my keyboard and AFTER THIS, the parent process print out my entered text in upper letters and print out the message "Hello, I am the parent process process. I've waited. "

Its exactly this order:

> Hello! I am the child process. Why does my parent process wait for me?
>
> Test input
>
> TEST INPUT
>
> Hello, I am the parent process process. I've waited.
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

But I excepted that both run parallel, so the parent process should exit before I've entered sth..
Also I can't understand why I get the text converted to upper letters before I get the message "Hello, I am the parent process process. I've waited.". In my code its the reversed order. At first I print out the information and after that, I print out the "test input" in upper case letters.

This is my code:
https://github.com/marvpaul/CPipesTest/blob/master/main.c

Comment: I played a little bit with this code and it seems that n = read(fd[0], zeile, MAX_ZEICHEN); waits for any input before continue. Right so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The read command will wait for the write command for this pipe.